# Configuring the squid server

Tags: networking, ubuntu, proxy

I want to create a proxy server on my second PC with UBUNTU.
I have done the initial settings and configurations but I am not sure how to initialize it.

```
 +--------+  LAN   +--------+   Hotspot   +---------+     
 | Win PC |  --->  | Ubuntu |    --->     | Win PC  |
 |        |        | +proxy |             |         |
 +--------+        +--------+             +---------+
```

- I have given the UBUNTU PC internet connection through my Windows PC on a LAN. I want to broadcast the *proxied* internet connection on the UBUNTU computer using hotspot.
- I have installed and run a proxy server ([`squid`](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/squid.html)) on the Ubuntu machine

But after all the configurations and everything when I connect to that hotspot, I am able to access the internet even without entering my proxy details on the test machine.

I guess I am missing something fundamental here. Please help.

What I want eventually is to create a proxy server on the UBUNTU PC which can be accessed through it's hotspot. The other devices that connect to that hotspot should not be able to access the internet without entering the right proxy settings in their browser.

Comment: Hey, so some new development in the time I was still tinkering. I was able to make the squid work and connect to it using a third pc and verify the proxy. However, the proxy server is not tunneling all of the internet. I want to route all the internet requests through the proxy and the user should not be able to access the internet without entering the proxy details, which is not happening right now. The client is able to access the internet with or without the proxy settings in the browser.

Comment: Anyone Anything? I'm sure there is some minor changes that I'm messing up and this should be easy to solve now. l'm just not sure where to look(except the documentation which is too big). Any help or direction will be really appreciated.

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser. Integrate your question with what you specified in your comments,  following the [edit] link, Make more clear how you physically/logically connected the devices and which is the result you desire...

Comment: You can pre-configure the proxy in all the Windows PC so that the user needs admin rights to remove them.

Comment: I have actually tried configuring the PC with the proxy(Using the IP address of the UBUNTU PC) but it doesn't seems to work.Is the proxy supposed to work automatically if you create a wireless network on the server and connect to it?

Comment: What IP address should be put when accessing the proxy server hotspot from another system? The native IP of the server system is not working. The hotspot gateway address is the only thing that has shown some response up till now. However, I am not able to access the internet with that IP setting. Any ideas?